# Bash condition that won't run on first Thursday of the month

Tags: bash, cron, date

I have a cron that runs a script twice a week (Monday/Thursday) - this runs fine, but I need to stop it processing on the first Thursday of the month.

I'd like to adapt this code:

```
we=$(LC_TIME=C date +%A)
dm=$(date +%d)
if [ "$we" = "Thursday" ] && [ "$dm" -lt 8 ]
then 
    .....
fi
```

I would assume I just change the = to != but wonder if there would be any gotchas I need to be aware of?

This question (where I got the code above from) is the [opposite of what I want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445854/bash-script-to-test-if-its-the-first-monday-of-the-month) - I would actually have preferred to add a comment to the accepted answer to ask this question, but I'd need 50 rep.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change the example code - `we` and `dm` are being set using `we=$(LC_TIME=C date +%A)` and `dm=$(date +%d)` same as the accepted answer on the linked question.

Comment: As a general rule, every question should stand on its own.  It's fine to link another question but I shouldn't have to go anywhere but here to understand your question.  If anything from the linked Q/A is relevant to your question it should be included in your question.

Comment: Fair comment - as I say I didn't really want to post a whole question to clarify one small point. But will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: _"I would assume I just change the = to != but wonder "_ -- `[ "$we" != "Thursday" ] && [ "$dm" -lt 8 ]` would be true on the first seven days of the month, except the Thursday.  Inverting the second test too would make the condition true on all non-Thursdays beginning at the 8th day of the month. Remember [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bash test:

```
if [[ "$(LC_TIME=C date +%A)" == 'Thursday' && "$(date +%d)" -le 7 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Note: Functionally this is no different than the test in your question.

Just add that to the top of your script.  If it is the first thursday of the month the script will exit right away, otherwise it will run.

Alternatively you could put it right into your crontab entry, something like:

```
0 1 * * 1,4 [[ "$(LC_TIME=C date +\%A)" == 'Thursday' && "$(date +\%d)" -le 7 ]] || /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great - thanks also for rewriting it :)

Comment: The script has other related tasks that need to continue to run - it's just one part of the script that needs to be passed over, so I can't put the date logic in my cron. I have just moved the code to the bottom of the script and put your condition above it.

Comment: `exit 0` might be more appropriate here, given that the script isn't even meant to run (i.e. it's not an error)